# Place div after div without js interops

Tags: blazor

I have a list of div elements that need to be placed within a form based on some varying criteria.

In JS I would just store them in a hidden div at the bottom of the form and move them into position when needed.
Simple JQuery   `$('#divToBeinserted').insertAfter($('#divExistingdiv'));`

Is there a way to do this in blazor/C# without using a js interop to pull it off?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not how to do it in Blazor.

Don't think of moving around DOM objects.  Since Blazor doesn't post back, there's no clientside advantage in moving things around in JS.

You should re-organize your *data itself* in C#, and use conditional logic in your markup to determine where to put things.

For example, let's say you have a collection of items, `List<CustomerInvoice> Invoices`, then the `@onclick` handler for the div that displays each could `Remove` that `CustomerInvoice`, `Insert` it into a new position in the `List`, and then you call the page to refresh with `StateHasChanged()`, and your `foreach` section will faithfully output everything in the new order.

There are definitely things you can't do in Blazor without Interop.  For example, if you want to get the selected text in an input, you'd use JS.  A lot of media things require JS as well-- recording audio, streaming video, etc. etc.  That's stuff is not covered in Blazor at all (yet?).

Comment: Yep thanks.  That's what I thought.

Basically what I'm doing right now is wrapping the div in an if statement to determine whether to show it or not.

Like so

@if (ShowShortTermNbaPromo())
            {
<div>all the form control data.....</div>
}

Which is shown based on a specific date range and some other criteria.
Most of these are relatively short term controls, compared to the rest of the form.
The version prior used typescript and kept all of the short term controls separate from the rest of the form and only inserted it into a location on the form when it was needed.

Comment: Yeah, that's the basic idea.  How you organize and display things is no more limited than C# itself.  One idea I've tried with some success is to have a `List<object>` with a switch on the class name in a `foreach` loop in the markup; then you can display any arbitrary list of class instances with whatever components you want, in whatever order you want.